# Yii2 migrations - Separated Migrations

Tags: yii2, database-migration, yii2-advanced-app

I am creating a module with the following structure:

```
common
L modules
LL blog
LLL backend
LLL frontend
LLL common
LLL migrations
```

I found in yii2 documentation a section about ["Separated Migrations"](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-migrations.html#separated-migrations)

In console/config/main.php I have set:

```
'migrate-blog' => [
            'class' => 'yii\console\controllers\MigrateController',
            'migrationNamespaces' => ['app\common\modules\blog\migrations'],
            'migrationTable' => 'migration_blog',
            'migrationPath' => null,
        ]
```

Then I go to console and run following command:

```
php yii migrate/create app\\common\\modules\\blog\\migrations\\create_table_blog_post
```

It returns an error:

```
Error: Namespace 'app\common\modules\blog\migrations' not found in `migrationNamespaces`
```

am I missing any settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you add the following info to config of console.php

```
'controllerMap' => [

    // Migrations for the specific project's module
    'migrate-module' => [
        'class' => 'yii\console\controllers\MigrateController',
        'migrationNamespaces' => ['app\module\migrations'],
        'migrationTable' => 'migration_module',
        'migrationPath' => null,
    ],
],
```

I have seen that you have the config in console/config/main.php then the check the **yii** file is having the following line.

```
$config = require(__DIR__ . '/console/config/main.php');
```

After this instead of running

```
php yii migrate/create app\\common\\modules\\blog\\migrations\\create_table_blog_post
```

Run the following command

```
php yii/migrate-blog/create create_table_blog_post
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks it solved the error, but the migration is created under console/migrations. I want to created migrations inside my module? is that migrationPath?

Comment: Did you give **migrationNamespaces** config in your configuration.
`'migrationNamespaces' => ['app\module\migrations'], `
It is actually enough if you use 
`php yii/migrate-blog/create create_table_blog_post`
Generally  **migrationPath** are used if migrations are in some other directories which are not in  **migrationNamespaces**.
If it is still doesn't solve your problem let me know. I hope this helps.